# Can you pass arguments to callback reference?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've constructed a simple hook in my project in order to re-use form fields.

> **What I'm trying to do:**
> Figure out a way to pass automatically pass an argument to a function reference to array of callback functions

This is fairly simply if you are only taking one argument into consideration. Consider the following function:

```
checkMinValue = (input: number) => input > 42 ? '' : `Must be bigger than 42`
```

and the hook defined the following way

```
import { useState, ChangeEvent } from 'react'

type Field = {
  value: any,
  errors: string[],
}

type CheckFunction = (...args: any[]) => string

const invokeMap = (input: any, checkFunctions: CheckFunction[]) => (
   checkFunctions.map(callback => callback(input)).filter(e => e !== '')
)

const useField = (value: any, checkFunctions: CheckFunction[]) => {
  const initialValue: Field = {
    value,
    errors: invokeMap(value, checkFunctions),
  }
  const [field, setField] = useState<Field>(initialValue)

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setField({
      value,
      errors: invokeMap(value, checkFunctions)
    })
  }

  return [field, handleChange]
}
```

So in actual code you'd have something like

```
const [age, handleAgeChange] = useField(12, [checkMinValue])
```

That code snippet above works like a charm *(although obviously in actual code it's bit more robust, but this should be enough to paint the picture)*

> **Where the issue arises:**
> I can't figure out a way to somehow be able to pass an argument to function reference.

So let's say I want to make my `checkMinValue` function a bit more dynamic.

```
checkMinValue = (input: number, min: number) => input >= min ? '' : `Must be bigger than ${min}`
```

Issue is, I can no longer simply pass the argument, as this would simply cause an invocation,

eg. `useField(8, [checkMinValue('//... nothign to pass here, 8)])` is obviously nonsense.

I was thinking about currying it and only passing function reference, but that leaves the issue with me having to basically limit myself to x amount of curries depending on how many arguments I need. And declaring an individual curry for each function is actually more of a time-waster than simply declaring the event handlers and stuff to begin with instead of using the hook.

Is there any way to reasonably approach this, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function that takes an input argument and returns a function. For your example you could do:

```
checkMinValue = (min) => (input: number) => input >= min ? '' : `Must be bigger than ${min}`
```

Now when you call checkMinValue(8) it returns a function that you can pass.